# Read specific attributes from a dictionary nested in an multidimensional array

Tags: node.js, arrays

An array in my code looks like this:

```
[
     {"ip":"127.0.0.1"},
     {"ip":"::1"}
]
```

This array is pretty short to return by reading specific indexes out of it, ie: `return Array(array[0].ip, array[1].ip).toString();` but what if the array is larger? Is there a way to and return all `ip` attributes from such an array?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve, please show an example of expected output. Further, please post the code that you tried writing and show what's the _actual_ output so we'll be able to better understand what is the issue you ran into.

Comment: See [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `Array.map`

```js
const ipList = [
     {"ip":"127.0.0.1"},
     {"ip":"::1"}
];

console.log(ipList.map(({ip}) => ip));
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `.map()` function:

```js
const ips = array.map(item => item.ip);
```

Comment: "ip" is not "all attributes".

Comment: OP is asking for "all `ip` attributes", not "all attributes"

Comment: see the title. It's not clear if the ip is used as an example or not and if they want to read only a single property or multiple ones. This question can't be answer until clarifications are provided!